# Kodi with split tunnel VPN

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vpn, kodi

I installed Kodi on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS on an Intel NUC. I installed a split tunnel where traffic goes through the usual internet connection with the exception of user2 who's traffic goes through a VPN. I tested by `$ curl ipinfo.io` and `$ sudo -u user2 -i -- curl ipinfo.io`.

First command shows my ISP's IP address and the second my VPN's IP address as expected. I did this to run Kodi under user2 while logged into Ubuntu under user1 (allows me to SSH into Ubuntu system under user1 which would not be possible if everything went through the VPN). From login screen I can run Kodi or Ubuntu for a number of users I set up. However I want to log into Ubuntu as user1, then within the Ubuntu session run Kodi under user2.

I thought I could log into Ubuntu as user1, open a terminal and run `$ su - user2`, then run Kodi by `$ sudo kodi`. I have to type `sudo kodi` instead of `kodi` otherwise Kodi does not run and gives a GUI error. However, doing this the Kodi user is user2 (user setup for VPN), but running the speed test app for Kodi shows the connection is not running through VPN. I know Kodi is through user2 as the add-ons I installed are the ones for Kodi under user2.

Why is Kodi using the user2 settings but not the VPN? Is this because of `sudo kodi`? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into Ubuntu as user1 as usual. Then simply switch to user2 and run Kodi under user2.

Answer (score 1):

Install kodi-standalone and run it with systemd then apply vpn split iptable rules for kodi user.

https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried that, unfortunately it did not work!